# CodeIgniter App compromised, strange dat file appearing in directory

Tags: php, security, codeigniter

Working for a client to resolve a website compromise. Guy has a CodeIgniter app that I thought at first was redirecting to a pharma spam site. Further investigation shows that upon processing of the search functionality of the site, the app is somehow creating a quickstart.dat file and placing it in the top level directory of the server, its not even a webroot directory.

This dat file is populated with the exact html which is causing the site to render the pharma spam stuff. Unfortunately I don't know enough about CodeIgniter apps to determine how this is happening. I've looked through both the /application/controllers/search.php file and the /application/views/search.php files, which if I am interpreting the CodeIgniter documention correctly are responsible for processing any requests with "search" in the URL?

None of those two files have anything suspicious in them. So I started grepping the entire directory, and still no dice.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction? What am I missing? What portion of CodeIgniter would be responsible for placing the dat file in the home directory?

Comment: I don't have much experience with CodeIgniter either, but first I'd take a look at all dependencies/common includes it uses, then compare all internal PHPs to the originals available for download on their site of the same version your client is using. Did you copy all the files and manage to reproduce it in another server/localhost?

Comment: if I was a hacker, and I got control of your website, I wouldnt secretly 'hack' codeigniter to do a redirect. its probably something more generic, like the htaccess file or apache.

Answer (score 0):

There are just so many things that could have happened. I'll try and list all ideas I have of what could possible have happened.

**You could try the following:**

- Check the .htaccess file if it contains anything
- Check the routes file in codeigniter which handles redirection, it is located at /application/config/routes.php and check if there are any re-directions in there.
- search through all php files using the command line and look for "base64_decode("
- Delete the .dat file perhaps?

You could also try and search for files with large hashstrings that are usually used to obfuscate code

```
find ./ -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep '[a-zA-Z0-9]\{400\}'
```